# ASP.NET Site Connecting to MSSQL as Wrong User with Integrated Security

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I'm having problems connecting to an MSSQL database in an ASP.NET Web Forms application. The error I get the is the user corp\earth3 can't connect. earth3 is the name of the computer ... the logged in user is corp\earth (a domain administrator) which is what works when connecting to the database using MSSQL Management Studio. I'm building the web app on Windows 10 and its being deployed for production use on a Windows 2012 server (which has the same connection problem as the win10 machine).

I've tried each of the following in web.config. This works while connecting to other database instances on the db server, but not on this one.

```
<add key="sqlConnectString" value="Data Source=db01\pd; Initial Catalog=PDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
<add key="sqlConnectString" value="Data Source=db01\pd; Initial Catalog=PDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I connect to the db using corp\earth?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is an IIS web site, what is the App pool identity set as?  or is the site being hosted in debug mode in the IDE?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? Also, what is your Server authentication set to in MSSQL Management Studio ("Windows Authentication" -or- "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode")?

Comment: Hi Brad. An app pool identity fix solves the problem. I created an application pool with an identity that works with the database. Now when I browse to the site it works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Identity in the application pool with a user that can connect to the database. Create a custom app pool if you don't want to make a change that would affect other web sites it uses.